# How to get oracle SQL function return in C# with ODBC?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, odbc

Here is the SQL function that I want to call :

Spec:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE PCK_GET_INFO AS 

  type tbl_acteur is table of Acteur%rowtype index by binary_integer;

  FUNCTION FNC_GET_ACTEURS RETURN tbl_acteur;

END PCK_GET_INFO;
```

Body:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY PCK_GET_INFO AS


  FUNCTION FNC_GET_ACTEURS RETURN tbl_acteur IS 
    tbl_acteur_inst tbl_acteur;

  BEGIN
    select * 
      bulk collect into tbl_acteur_inst
      from Acteur;

    RETURN tbl_acteur_inst;
 END FNC_GET_ACTEURS;

END PCK_GET_INFO;
```

And my C# code :

```
        OdbcDataReader DbReader;
        OdbcCommand Cmd = new OdbcCommand("{? = call SMI1002_33.PCK_GET_INFO.FNC_GET_ACTEURS()}", connOracle);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OdbcParameter prm = Cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", OdbcType.Int);
        prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        DbReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But I got an error... I know that the return type of my function isn't an Int but I can't find the way to get the data from my C# code..

Comment: You cannot return a pl/sql collection to ODBC.  You need to use a ref cursor.

Comment: Hi OldProgrammer! Do you know where I can find an example of this?

Comment: Please don't be lazy.  Google and find many links - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322160

Comment: I searched a lot about it and I only find way to do this with OracleConnection, but I'm trying to do it with OdbcConnection and there's no odbcType.cursor. Is that just impossible to do this with odbc?

Comment: As far as I've found, you have to use a SQL select as your CommandText and call ExecuteReader(...) to get a result set from Oracle.  RefCursors just don't work via ODBC.  (Works great in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess!)